# Ruby find key by name inside converted JSON array of hashes

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I have a Ruby hash converted from JSON data, it looks like this:

```
{ :query => {
    :pages => { 
      :"743958" => { 
        :pageid => 743958, 
        :ns => 0, 
        :title => "Asterix the Gaul", 
        :revisions => [ {
          :contentformat => "text/x-wiki", 
          :contentmodel => "wikitext", 
          :* => "{{Cleanup|date=April 2010}}\n{{Infobox graphic novel\n<!--Wikipedia:WikiProject Comics-->...
```

All the good stuff is inside the `revisions` array and then the `Infobox` hash.

The problem I have is getting to the `Infobox` hash. I can't seem to get to it. The `pages` and `pageid` hashes might not exist for other entries and of course the ID would be different.

I've tried all sorts of methods I could think of like `.map`, `.select`, `.find`, `.include?`, etc to no avail because they are not recursive and will not go into each key and array.

And all the answers I've seen in StackOverflow are to get the value by name inside a one-dimensional array which doesn't help.

How can I get the `Infobox` data from this?

Comment: ... Where do you get stumped? You'll need to parse the content within `*` manually since it's not in any format, getting to `*` is simple object traversal.

Comment: I get stumped in 2 places: 1. getting to *, I can't get to it. Then I'll need to figure out a way to parse the contents of `Infobox`.

Comment: It's in the first array element of `revisions`, roughly `[:query][:pages]["743958"][:revisions][0]["*"]. Parsing it totally depends on what the data *actually* looks like, it could be as simple as splitting on `}}\n{{`, it could be worse.

Comment: Yes, that much I know, my problem, as stated in the original question, is how do I traverse all the way to `*` and get its data when I don't know the names of the keys preceding it? Specifically the ID. Is the question not clear so I can edit it?

Comment: If you don't know the id then it depends on what data you're getting in toto. If you have only a single ID returned then it's obvious. If you have multiple IDs returned then it's obvious, but iterative.

Comment: Thanks Dave, but if it were that `obvious` to me I wouldn't have asked in Stack Overflow and wasted my time and yours. Anyway, @Skram answered it. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
pp data
 => {:query=>   {:pages=>
      {:"743958"=>
        {:pageid=>743958,
         :ns=>0,
         :title=>"Asterix the Gaul",
         :revisions=>
          [{:contentformat=>"text/x-wiki",
            :contentmodel=>"wikitext",
            :*=>"{{Cleanup..."}]}}}}


# just return data from the first revisionb
data[:query][:pages].map{|page_id,page_hash| page_hash[:revisions].first[:"*"]}
 => ["{{Cleanup..."] 


# get data from all revisions
data[:query][:pages].map{|page_id,page_hash| page_hash[:revisions].map{|revision| revision[:"*"]  }}.flatten
 => ["{{Cleanup..."]
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it! I just couldn't figure it out, many, many thanks!